# Can people on the same ticket separately check-in at airline counter?

Tags: air-travel, airports, check-in

If one of the passengers has not reached airport yet, can the rest check-in while the remaining check-in later (to get their boarding pass)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each person is issued a separate ticket, you may all be on the same *reservation*, that is, have the same confirmation number but each passenger is given an individual ticket, even if they don't occupy a seat (as in the case of infants).

If you are all travelling on the same reservation number, <strike>then you must check-in at the same time; otherwise the missing people are at risk of being classified as "no-show" which may have financial penalties depending on the type of ticket.</strike>

Apparently, there is no hard and fast rule on this (as per Zach's comment). I would call the airline and ask to be sure.

For me, I have yet to be in a situation where separate check-ins are allowed for the same reservation.

Comment: I've checked in at different times from other people on the same reservation number (both online and in person, usually on United). Nobody seems to think it's a problem as long as everyone checks in by the deadline.

Comment: It is strange because I have been asked to wait till all members of the party have arrived. It may be an airline policy? Mind you I rarely travel domestic so it may also have to do with the destination. In fact on my last trip, everyone had to walk up to the check-in desk and I couldn't just take their electronic check-in receipts (although this may be more of a restriction of the airport rather than the airline).

Comment: Interesting. I imagine like many things to do with air travel, it can depend on the airline/airport/destination/particular agent you happen to get/phase of the moon. I haven't done it very many times since online checkin is often available now.